# selecionar duas tabelas utilizando where

Tags: php, sql, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho uma tabela de `produtos (id,id_categoria,nome,descricao)` e uma tabela de `imagens (id, FileName, id_produto)`.

Preciso listar dados do produto e uma imagem da tabela relacionado ao produto pelo id.

```
$sql = $mysqli->query
("SELECT
   produtos.nome,
   imagens.FileName
FROM
   produtos
INNER JOIN
   imagens ON produtos.id_produto = imagens.id_produto
WHERE produtos.id_produto = '".$_GET['id']."'");
```

Comment: Qual o erro ou dificuldade que está a encontrar?

Comment: não tá funcionando

Comment: conseguiu entender a minha dúvida?

Comment: Está a tentar fazer uma consulta com php e mysql e não está a funcionar é isso ? qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: A primeira parte do join não me parece correta. Deveria ser `ON produtos.id = imagens.id_produto`. E aconselho a testar a consulta no phpMyAdmin ou equivalente com um id a sua escolha para perceber melhor o problema

Comment: alterei mas não deu certo: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Faça `echo($mysqli->error);` para ter uma descrição mais concreta do erro que tem na consulta

Comment: Talvez eu não soube me expressar, é o seguinte:
Estou listando produtos de um categoria pelo get.
Nesta listagem aparece os produtos tudo certinho, porém não está aparecendo a imagem, que está numa terceira tabela.
Então eu tenho 3 tabelas:
- categorias
- produtos
- imagens

Comment: Até aqui tudo bem: $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria = '".$_GET['id']."'");

Answer (score 0):

O erro apresentado:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Indica algum problema com a query. Pode ser um campo com nome errado, ou o id está sendo passado de forma incorreta. Para ter certeza, tente colocar este código depois do seu comando $mysqli->query, pra ver o que pode estar errado

```
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: não mudou muita coisa: Error:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: O seu $_GET['id'] está trazendo algum dado? Pode ser que esteja vindo em branco.
Teste trocando o trecho por um id fixo, apenas pra testar.

Ex.:
(... ) WHERE produtos.id_produto = "0001"

Comment: Talvez eu não soube me expressar, é o seguinte:
Estou listando produtos de um categoria pelo get.
Nesta listagem aparece os produtos tudo certinho, porém não está aparecendo a imagem, que está numa terceira tabela.
Então eu tenho 3 tabelas:
- categorias
- produtos
- imagens

Comment: Até aqui tudo certo: $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria = '".$_GET['id']."'");   Eu preciso apenas pegar a imagem que esta numa terceira tabela

Comment: 1) Pode ser que não tenha um correspondente deste ID de produto na tabela de imagens. Existe uma imagem relacionada com este ID?
2) Checou se o nome das colunas está correto, inclusive considerando Case-Sensitive? **FileName** pode ser diferente de **filename**
3) Se vc rodar essa consulta direto no banco, ela retorna algum resultado?

Comment: tem sim: id, FileName e id_produto

Comment: Cleber como foi expliquei: Até aqui tá tudo certo: $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria = '".$_GET['id']."'");  Eu preciso apenas pegar a imagem que esta numa terceira tabela

Comment: tá listando tudo Ok, apenas a imagem não listou

Comment: E a consulta que você colocou no começo da pergunta? A com o INNER JOIN. Ela retorna algo se vc tentar consultar direto no banco?

Comment: Aquela sintaxe eu pesquisei e tentei aplicar, mas não de certo.

Comment: Vc tem um PHPMyAdmin ou alguma outra interface que permita rodar a query direto, sem ser pelo código PHP?
Aparentemente, tudo está correto. Inclusive criei as tabelas aqui e rodei, sem erro :/

Comment: Estou no local host, quer ver a estrutura do banco?

Comment: Tenho três tabelas
categorias (id, nome)
produtos (id, id_categoria, nome, descricao)
imagens (id, FileName, id_produto)

Estou listando todos os produtos vinculados a categoria pelo id Get
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria = '".$_GET['id']."'");

Listagem correta, porém os produtos não aparece a imagem da capa.

Comment: O que eu precisava era pegar a imagem da tabela imagens, apenas isso.

Comment: Talvez nem seria o uso do INNER JOIN

Comment: Enfim... parece tão simples, ao mesmo tempo não.

Comment: Por que não assim?

`"SELECT FileName FROM imagens WHERE id_produto = '".$_GET['id']."'"`

Comment: Boa noite Cleber! Assim não rolou, pq eu preciso pegar o id e nome do produto que está na tbl produtos